# Order By Combined

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions, normalization, sql-function

I have a result set where I want to apply a combined sort combined.

Example

> SELECT Id, Name FROM Users

Result

```
Id  Name   
1   Albert
2   Alfred
3   Carl
4   David
5   Ernest
```

Now those users could be orderd by last access, last post, number of comments made or calculated parameters. How could i order if i have a SELECT like this:

> SELECT Id, Name, function_last_access(Id) as f1,
>   function_last_post(Id) as f2, function_calculate_parameters(Id) as f3
>   FROM Users

```
Id  Name     f1   f2   f3
1   Albert   2    100  1,1
2   Alfred   10   20   2
3   Carl     0    15   5
4   David    5    2    3
5   Ernest   4    5    1
```

It's better to take different ordered lists and combine them after?
Or put them in columns and then apply a normalization function and then sort them?

Could help me ORDER BY PARTITION or something like that?

Comment: Please show the expected output, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I must first normalize functions to a single factor so as to make them comparable. In the sense that for f1 top could be 10, but for f2 top could be 0 and f3 could be 1,1... Once normalized to a single scale could then add them and order them for example.

Comment: Still no clear. *Please show the expected output*

Comment: I don't know until i give a weighed to my function as show in Adomar's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the aliases to a subquery so you can refer to them in the `order by`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  Id
        ,       Name
        ,       function_last_access(Id) as f1
        ,       function_last_post(Id) as f2
        ,       function_calculate_parameters(Id) as f3 
        FROM    Users
        ) as SubQueryAlias
order by
        0.3 * f3 + 0.2 * f2 + 0.1 * f3 desc
```

Comment: If i make an order like that i give more value to f1 than f2 and f3. I'd like to normalize value on same standard and than order.

Comment: If the functions return a number, you could use a weighed average, updated in answer.  Not that user-defined functions typically do not perform well enough to be useful in a search algorithm.  A CLR function might perform well enough, but is not trivial to write and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
SELECT Id, Name, f1, f2, f3
FROM 
(
  SELECT Id, 
    Name, 
    function_last_access(Id) as f1, 
    function_last_post(Id) as f2, 
    function_calculate_parameters(Id) as f3 
  FROM Users
) f
ORDER BY f1, f2, f3
```

Comment: If i make an order like that i give more value to f1 than f2 and f3. I'd like to normalize value on same standard and than order.

Comment: I think I'd need to see your desired output -- a little unclear as to what you want.

Comment: I don't know until i give a weighed to my function as show in Adomar's answer.